# To wish luck "at" or "in"?

Tags: grammar

What sentence is more correct?

> I wish you luck *in* your studies.

Or

> I wish you luck *at* your studies.

Or the both variants can be used?

Comment: *in* definitely sounds more natural to me. I can't say that I remember hearing *at* used like this.

Comment: @Addison I agree *in* sounds more natural in that context, but I would sometimes use *at* ("I'm going to try my luck at cards") or *on* ("Good luck on the horses").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow *good luck* with a variety of expressions. You can also precede *studies* with a variety of expressions.

For example, a young man might be busy *at his studies* in the evenings. He may struggle *with his studies*, only to succeed *in his studies* after much hard work.

Generally speaking, if you can put a noun at the end of a phrase, you can put *good luck* in front of the phrase and have it make sense.  If you want to sound “natural”, look at (or imagine) the spoken sentence that might have preceded the wishing of good luck.